# How to make a samba server available on internet with SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, samba, smb, nas

I have a local samba server running on my raspberry pi that I use as a NAS to share files with other devices on the network. How can I use SSH to make this accessible (with a password) over the internet so I can access my files from anywhere?

Comment: Why did you delete your last question? It can help others.

Answer (score 0):

The ssh related part of this question has alread good answers in [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/968641/setting-up-server-to-connect-using-ssh-over-the-internet-ubuntu-14-04).

I strongly recommend not to use username/password authentication for external access, but restrict the access with public/private keys.

And it is not a good idea to open the samba access to the internet, so this question is not related to `samba` and `smb`.

Another solution would be to install a NAS software on your device. The benefit will be, that you can access your files with a web browser, have user management and you can enable a lot of other functions.
You can try [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/), [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.com/) or [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/owncloud/?platform=self-hosted).